# Can't switch between Console mode and GUI

Tags: 12.04, gui, console, function-keys

I'm new to Linux/Ubuntu and experiencing the following problem:
I start my computer, and get to the GUI where I can login. When I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> I will get to the first of the consoles, everything is fine so far. But now I can't switch back to the GUI. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or only <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (I have tried both), the screen goes completely black and there is nothing I can do.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> will NOT bring me back to the console, neither does any other <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> combination.

Sometimes (and I'm not sure what it depends on whether it works or not) I can switch back to the GUI once. But if I then go to the console again and try to go back to the GUI a third time, it never works.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit on a very old (7 years) Fujitsu Siemens Laptop (Intel Pentium(R) M Processor 2.00 GHz; 1GB Memory). Could it be a hardware problem?
Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: try to add the `fn` key to the combo, since it's a laptop you probably have a different "key behaviour". something like CTRL+ALT+fn+F7 or similar.

Comment: try `startx` command

Answer (score 1):

When at the console, type:

```
startx
```

If this works, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to get back to the console.

If 'startx' doesn't work, and it throws up errors, edit the question with those errors.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Hi, I tried it and got the following error: "Fatal Server Error: Server is already active for display 0 <br> If this server is no longer running, remove /tmpT.X0-lock and start again <br>(EE)<br>Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support"

Comment: Ok, try this: 'sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop' and reboot.

Comment: If I ran service lightdm stop, this brings an empty screen. Is there a way to get back to the console?